# Flutter + firestore : filter list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that gets documents from firestore.

```
  List<Post> posts;
  List<Post> filteredposts;

  void getDeals() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('deals')
        .document('${widget.stad.toLowerCase()}')
        .collection('deals')
        .orderBy('endTime', descending: false)
        .getDocuments();
    List<Post> posts =
        snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
    setState(() {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }
```

I would like to filter that list e.x. where the bool: (in the firestore document) "typeX" is equalto true.

```
  setState(() {
      filteredposts = posts.where((snapshot) => snapshot.typeX == true);
    });
```

But I get the error message:

```
'WhereIterable<Post>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Post>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Change it to `filteredposts = posts.where((snapshot) => snapshot.typeX == true).toList();`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much for the quick and efficient answer!

Comment: @ChennaReddy Hello, would you mind posting the solution as an answer so it gets more visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the `List`/`Iterable` helper methods like `map`, `where`, `expand`... etc return a variant of `Iterable` but not `List` as the underlying data structure need not be a List (e.g. it can be a `Set`).

So most of the times, you need to call `toSet` or `toList` on the result of these methods.

In your case it would be

```
filteredposts = posts.where((snapshot) => snapshot.typeX == true).toList();
```